# Getting null from DB while running integration test using TestContainer

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, testcontainers

I am learning Java, Spring and I came across the TestContainers library for writing (unit/integration) tests. I tried to write a sample application, made a RabbitMQ producer, consumer, then I wrote a test case for it as below:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SampleITTest extends AbstractTestcontainers {
    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    private static final String QUEUE_URI = "/api/v1/queue";
    private final RabbitTemplate producerWithRoutingKey;
    @Autowired
    public RabbitMQIntegrationTest(RabbitTemplate producerWithRoutingKey) {
        this.producerWithRoutingKey = producerWithRoutingKey;
    }

    @Test
    void pushMessageToRabbitWhenHitEndPoint() {
        webTestClient.get()
                .uri(QUEUE_URI + "/send")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .isOk();

        List<QueueMessage> messages = webTestClient.get()
                .uri(QUEUE_URI)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .isOk()
                .expectBodyList(new ParameterizedTypeReference<QueueMessage>() {
                })
                .returnResult()
                .getResponseBody();

        assertThat(messages).isNotEmpty();
    }

    @Test
    void shouldGiveMessageWhenStoredMessageInDBThroughRabbitMQ() {
        String title = "Sending Message To Queue";
        String description = "We are testing the testContainer";

        SendMessage message = new SendMessage(title, description);

        producerWithRoutingKey
                .convertAndSend("testContainerExchange", "routing-key", message);

        List<QueueMessage> listMessages = webTestClient.get()
                .uri(QUEUE_URI)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .isOk()
                .expectBodyList(new ParameterizedTypeReference<QueueMessage>() {
                })
                .returnResult()
                .getResponseBody();

        QueueMessage actualMessage = listMessages.stream()
                        .filter(m -> m.getTitle().equals(message.title()))
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElseThrow();

        assertThat(actualMessage.getTitle()).isEqualTo(message.title());
        assertThat(actualMessage.getDescription()).isEqualTo(message.description());
    }
}
```

When I run both the test separately, they work fine as I get a pass, but when I run all the tests, then in the second test shouldGiveMessageWhenStoredMessageInDBThroughRabbitMQ(), I get listMessage as null.

I am not sure why I am getting this behaviour and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing a common challenge when writing integration tests: tests interfere with each other due to shared state. The shared state, in this case, might be RabbitMQ's message queues, databases, or caches. When you run your tests individually, the shared state from the first test does not affect the second. However, when you run them together, the leftover state from the first test might interfere with the second.

So I think there are a few tips on how to resolve your issue:

1. **Reset State**: Ensure a clean state before each test, like resetting RabbitMQ queues.
2. **Fresh RabbitMQ Instance**: Use TestContainers to start a fresh RabbitMQ instance for each test.
3. Wait for Asynchronous Operations: RabbitMQ is asynchronous. Implement retry logic to wait for messages, rather than just expecting immediate availability.
4. **Check Test Setup**: Ensure there's no setup inconsistency like naming errors.
5. **Test Scoping**: Narrow down the Spring context for your tests using annotations like @WebFluxTest or @DataJpaTest.
6. **Use @DirtiesContext**: Resets the Spring context after each test to ensure no lingering state.

Note, for the following questions you ask please add an environment you are testing on (i.e., architecture, operating system and framework version). So that other people could reproduce your issue and help you immediately.